# how to extend the row which include NA in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe D :

```
D=matrix(c(1,4,1,4,2,NA,4,2,3,2,1,3,4,3,2,1),nrow=4,ncol=4)
D<-as.data.frame(D)
> D
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  2  3  4
2  4 NA  2  3
3  1  4  1  2
4  4  2  3  1
```

I want to expand the row which include the NA. 
What I expect is that:

```
> expect.D
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  2  3  4
2  4  1  2  3
3  4  2  2  3
4  4  3  2  3
5  4  4  2  3
6  1  4  1  2
7  4  2  3  1
```

Of course ,There are several possible cases will occur in dataframe D 
e.g.

```
> D
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  2  3  4
2  4 NA NA  3
3  1  4  1  2
4  4  2  3  1
```

And the result I expect is that:

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4
   1  2  3  4
   4  1  1  3
   4  2  1  3
   4  3  1  3
   4  4  1  3
   4  1  2  3
   4  2  2  3
   4  3  2  3
   4  4  2  3
   4  1  3  3
   4  2  3  3
   4  3  3  3
   4  4  3  3
   4  1  4  3
   4  2  4  3
   4  3  4  3
   4  4  4  3
   1  4  1  2
   4  2  3  1
```

Comment: You haven't specified *in what manner* you want to expand the row. Are you expanding it according to the number in `V1`? What happens if `V1` is `NA`. You should really add some explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to expand the NA to have 4 rows, one for each of the possibilities 1,2,3,4. So a row of: 1, NA, 3, 4 would become

```
1, 1, 3, 4
1, 2, 3, 4
1, 3, 3, 4
1, 4, 3, 4
```

replacing that row in the data.frame.

Then something like this might do:

```
do.call("rbind",
      lapply(1:nrow(D),
             function(row) {
               if (any(is.na(D[row, ]))) {
                 expand.grid(sapply(D[row, ], function(values) {
                   if (is.na(values)) {
                     1:4
                   } else {
                     values
                   }
                 }))
               } else {
                 D[row, ]
               }
             }))
```

Someone might have a more elegant solution, but it should work, even with multiple NAs per row.

Hope it helps.

:)